# Here Batch Geocode API - Batch stuck on Submitted status

Tags: here-api

I have submitted a job to Here.com to Geocode 5 Addresses.  I submitted using Postman using a POST request.  I submitted it on Wednesday and now it is Friday and the status when I check still says "Submitted".

Here is the api request I used:

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?app_id=ID&app_code=CODE&mailto=billtepe@gmail.com&outdelim=|&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country&indelim=|
```

Data:

```
recId|searchText|country
1|1 BRAID WAY TAYLOR MILL KY 41011|USA
2|1 GEORGETOWN FORT MITCHELL KY 41017|USA
3|1 SPERTI DR  KY|USA
4|10 E. 29TH ST. TAYLOR MILL KY 41015|USA
5|1000 W 33RD ST LATONIA KY 41015|USA
```

Response I got back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <RequestId>bEmNvFu9M7AVaISeEYvrT4cYMlj29Y8K</RequestId>
        </MetaInfo>
        <Status>submitted</Status>
        <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
        <ValidCount>0</ValidCount>
        <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
        <ProcessedCount>0</ProcessedCount>
        <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
        <SuccessCount>0</SuccessCount>
        <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
    </Response>
</ns2:SearchBatch>
```

---

Here is the GET request I submit through POSTMAN to check on the status:

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs/bEmNvFu9M7AVaISeEYvrT4cYMlj29Y8K?app_id=ID&app_code=CODE&action=status
```

and here is the response I've been getting for 2.5 days now.  How long should this take?  I'm new to Here and just don't know what my expectations should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <RequestId>bEmNvFu9M7AVaISeEYvrT4cYMlj29Y8K</RequestId>
        </MetaInfo>
        <Status>submitted</Status>
        <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
        <ValidCount>0</ValidCount>
        <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
        <ProcessedCount>0</ProcessedCount>
        <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
        <SuccessCount>0</SuccessCount>
        <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
    </Response>
</ns2:SearchBatch>
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be a queue issue due to large number of requests. Please try submitting your request once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you did not start the job by adding "&action=run" to the POST request. Please check with the documentation at https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/submit-batch-request.html

You can start the job separately by sending a PUT request with that action.
The job will then change into status "ACCEPTED". Only then it will be queued for execution:

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs/bEmNvFu9M7AVaISeEYvrT4cYMlj29Y8K?app_id=ID&app_code=CODE&action=run
```

Comment: Thank You.  I eventually figured that out.  Thanks for your help!